# php code needed for my uploading file page

Tags: php, file-upload, web

i am currently making a website where i can upload a file and this file can be image or documents or application or any other types of file,
so once i upload the file it will display on my website interface the listed file with the size of the file and the date of uploading. 
but i don't know who is the user that uploaded it, 
yet i have no idea what is the coding in order to display together a long the size of the file and the date, the user who uploaded
will be grateful if someone help with the php code or even any solution for this matter 
thank you.

```
      <?php 
       //Load the settings
       require_once("Setting.php");
       require_once("db.php");
       $message = "";
       //Has the user uploaded something?
       if(isset($_FILES['file']))
       {
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$target_path = Setting::$uploadFolder;  
$target_path = $target_path . time() . '_' . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 
echo $target_path;

    //Try to move the uploaded file into the designated folder
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
    {
        $message = "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";

        $query ="insert into upload (path) values ('$target_path')";

    $dbresult = mysql_query($query,$dblink);

    } else{
        $message = "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
}

//Clear the array
unset($_FILES['file']);

    if(strlen($message) > 0)
    {
$message = '<p class="error">' . $message . '</p>';
    }

    /** LIST UPLOADED FILES **/
    $uploaded_files = "";

    //Open directory for reading
    $dh = opendir(Setting::$uploadFolder);

    //LOOP through the files
     while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) 
    {
if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
{

    $filename = Setting::$uploadFolder . $file;
    $parts = explode("_", $file);
    $size = formatBytes(filesize($filename));
    $added = date("m/d/Y", $parts[0]);
    $origName = $parts[1];
    $filetype = getFileType(substr($file, strlen($file) - 3));
     $uploaded_files .= "<li class=\"$filetype\"><a href=\"$filename\">$origName</a>          $size - $added</li>\n";

}

    }
    closedir($dh);

    if(strlen($uploaded_files) == 0)
    {
$uploaded_files = "<li><em>No files found</em></li>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `Give me teh codez`.... A simple Google search consisting of only 3 keywords `php` and `file upload` would have given you innumerable tutorials

Comment: Welcome to Coders R Us. We're currently experiencing difficulties with your problem as we have no idea what you've tried. Please come back when you've given us some idea of what you've already tried

Comment: ok here r my code, so i want to assign on my file list field which user has uploaded the file.
 @Asprin

Comment: @asprin plz refer to the above code, all i want is once a user logging into the website then upload the file, i want to display the username who uploaded can u help me with that thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easy steps :

1. You need from the user to signup in your site, look to this [tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/44787-creating-loginregistration-forms-with-php/)
2. after that user log in in your site you will have his ID in session so you can use it all over your web application
3. The user now can access the page that he will use for uploading look to this [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) on how to upload files to your server

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this basic tutorial on PHP file uploads on W3Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

The information relating to your file upload will be stored in the `$_FILES` variable

The file size is stored in `$_FILES["file"]["size"]` (where "file" is the name of the form field).

If the file has just been uploaded you can get the current date by using the PHP [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function and `echo` it out. If you're looking for the modification time of the file you can use [filemtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php).

As for the user, that will depend on your specific application.

Comment: Don't encourage w3schools

Comment: Please avoid link answers. Use it as a comment otherwise

Comment: Why not link to official PHP documentation? There are examples.

Comment: From the way the question was phrased, I assumed the user had little knowledge on the subject and opted for a tutorial aimed more at his level.

Comment: You should never refer anyone to w3schools, even if the person is so new that they don't know the concept of `if`. That site is simply dangerous and bad beyond words.

Comment: What is dangerous is that with all these tutorials people don't even know there is an official documentation.

Comment: I'm aware that there is out of date and bad content on the site. Have you looked at the page I posted? Sure you wouldn't use it in production, but for a beginners demonstration and an overview it's adequate. I agree @hidden_4003, but sometimes for new programmers the documentation can be confusing and they don't usually show full contextual examples.